# Nodejs:Instance of modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, instance

I understand requiring modules and what not but I would like to have instances of the module to use, kind of like an instance of a class for a java project or whatever. I have this code in my app.js:

```
var number = require("./number.js");
var numbers = [number.setNumber(2),
               number.setNumber(3),
               .....];
```

I have inside the number.js:

```
var number = -1;
exports.setNumber(num){
    number = num;
}
exports.getNumber(){
    return number;
}
```

I hope that it is sort of clear what I'm trying to do here, but I either can't find anywhere that it is explained on google, or I'm not sure what question to ask...so I hope this isn't a duplicate.

**QUESTION:** How do I create instances of modules/Can I create instances of modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself because although the answers given helped they were incomplete. 
I created what seems like a javascript class similar to an answer already given that has a constructor and all other "class methods" as prototypes. Key piece though was to `export` it.

```
var myNumber = function(num) {
    this.num = num
}

myNumber.prototype.setNumber = function(num) {
    this.num = num
}

myNumber.prototype.getNumber = function() {
    return this.num
}
module.exports = myNumber
```

Then, in the node its being required in I have:

```
var myNumber = require('./number.js');

var numbers = [ new myNumber(2), 
            new myNumber(3),
            new myNumber(3),
            new myNumber(4),
            new myNumber(4),
            new myNumber(5),
            new myNumber(5),
            new myNumber(6),
            new myNumber(6),
            new myNumber(8),
            new myNumber(8),
            new myNumber(9),
            new myNumber(9),
            new myNumber(10),
            new myNumber(10),
            new myNumber(11),
            new myNumber(11),
            new myNumber(12)];
```

This is what gives me the 20 or so different myNumber objects I was looking for. I don't know if I'm using the `module.exports = myNumber` correctly, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Modules are just a way to organize your code. The `object`, or another type, that you export from module by `module.exports =` is the thing, that you requiring with `require`

So you want something like Java Class, you can create a constructor

```
var Number = function(num) {
  this.num = num
}

Number.prototype.setNumber = function(num) {
  this.num = num
}

Number.prototype.getNumber = function() {
  return this.num
}
```

and in your other modules you can create a new instance of Number with `new` keyword

```
var Number = require('./number.js')
var myNum = new Number(3)
myNum.setNumber(4);
// ... so on
```

Comment: When I reassign with `myNum.setNumber(4)`, does that create a new Number object?

Comment: Also do I still need to export the Number "class"?

Comment: I wouldn't use the name `Number` for a user defined class, as it's already a built-in.

Comment: Yeah, name `Number` isn't good for that, just for example.

discodane, `module.exports = Number`
and when you reassign number you don't create new Object, cause it only change object property